# Convert string/char to double and following calculation with the double

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion

I have a string pointed by a pointer, and I want to convert that string into a double type number for calculation. However, I am not sure if my string is a `string` or a `char*` and whether I accessed the string pointed by pointer correctly. The following is my code:

```
void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());
    std::string str = msg->data;
    ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", str.c_str());
    double fmsg = std::atof(str.c_str());
    ROS_INFO("I am making calculation: [%d]", fmsg+1.0);
}
```

The `double` type cannot be recognized, and thus `fmsg+1.0` result in ten digit numbers or so. Could anyone help?

Comment: You have '%d' instead of '%lf'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, since you are using `c_str`, your strings cannot be of type `char*`; most likely they are `std::string`.

In addition, you don't need to create a copy of your string: `std::string str = msg->data` is superfluous (even though it doesn't hurt).

As for the bad output you get - Shashwat Kumar points out that your code doesn't print the number correctly, even though the number itself is correct. If `ROS_INFO` has the same syntax as `printf`, use `%lf` or `%f` format specifier to print a number of type `double`:

```
ROS_INFO("I am making calculation: [%f]", fmsg + 1);
```

(also, no need to spell `1` as `1.0`; you may prefer `1.0` if you think it's better)